# How can I add sub menu to my tabs?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, tabs

I have been struggling the whole morning trying to add dropdown menus to a simple tabbed content I have on my page.
I'd like to have dropdown menus (containing 4 items) displayed when the user clicks on a tab. The dropdown menu should then stay visible until the user clicks on another tab.

Any idea how to implement it to the below? I guess it is pretty easy ...

Thanks so much!

```
<style type="text/css">
            ul.tabs {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
            height: 32px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
            border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
            width: 100%;
            }
            ul.tabs li {
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0px 21px ;
            height: 31px;
            line-height: 31px;
            border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
            border-left: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #EEEEEE;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            }
            ul.tabs li:hover {
            background: #4b4b4b;
            }
            ul.tabs li.active{
            background: #FFFFFF;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
            }
            .tab_container {
            border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
            border-top: none;
            clear: both;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            background: #FFFFFF;
            }
            .tab_content {
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-family: arial;
            color: #4b4b4b;
            display: none;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".tab_content").hide();
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

        $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tab_content").hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
            $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
        });
    });
    </script>

    <html>
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active" rel="tab1">TAB1</li>
    <li rel="tab2">TAB2</li>
    <li rel="tab3">TAB3</li>
    </ul>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so scratch what i just did and check this one out. I think it might work better for what you're after.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VerdeletG/7s5szjkh/1/)

you can change the a tags to li if you wish!

to edit the look of your active tab, watch for:

```
.active_tab{
}
```

and to edit the looks of your tab content edit:

```
.tabCont{
}
```

Hope it's right this time!

Comment: Thanks!

It doesn't appear to be working with my tabs though.

Comment: by the way, i did something similar a while ago in terms of content display. [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/VerdeletG/dtZLU/21/). it'll work on an html page as long as the js-script (separate file or if the script is present on the page) is included within the body. in case you want it!

Comment: That would be amazing! Thanks mate

Comment: This is pretty much the result I initially have. I am trying to add a dropdown menu to the first tab. I have added some more explanations in an answer below. Thanks!

Comment: ohhhhhhhh so you want a drop down on the first tab? as in when you click on it you get an amazon.co.uk type menu, or a hovering menu?

Comment: [It should be better now, i think.](http://jsfiddle.net/VerdeletG/7s5szjkh/2/) Let me know what you think?

Comment: Ah yeah! That's very close to what I am trying to achieve! Is there a lot to change in my current code to get a result similar to what you've done in your opinion? Thanks!!

Comment: the containers work to size to the maximum height and width it takes up. adding extra links won't change much, and the same should work for placing a sub-menu on another link. adding a sub to THAT is different. It works for every container, as it erases the content of the first tab and third tab if you're in the second tab, and so on. if not, just comment again!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like i'm doing something bad with jQuery here, but the following code sounds like the thing you are after:

```
$('li').on('mouseover', function()
{
    var subMenu = '<ul id="subM" style="padding-left:'+this.offsetLeft+'px"> <li>First</li> </ul>';
    if(!$('#subM').length > 0)
    {
        $('body').append(subMenu);
    }
});

$('li').on('mouseout', function()
    {
        if($('#subM').is(':hover'))
        {
            $('#subM').on('mouseout', function()
            {
                $('#subM').remove();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#subM').remove();      
        }
    });
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7s5szjkh/

I've left the code you had untouched, just edit the content of the sub menu variable to show what you want. 
 
Plus I guess you might want different sub menus per tab, but this is just a starting point.

Comment: This is pretty much the result I initially have, this part is currently working properly with the code I have linked at the top. I am trying to add a dropdown menu to the first tab. I have added some more explanations in an answer below. THanks! –